# Nested Directives

Tags: angularjs

I have two directives one which translates strings and one which creates a container with a title. (and some other functionality that was removed to make the example shorter)

Groupbox:

```
myapp.directive('groupbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        priority: 200,
        template:
            '<fieldset>' +
            '<legend data-translate>{{title}}</legend>' +
            '<div data-ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</fieldset>',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        scope: {title: '@'}
    };
});
```

Translate: (also simplified)

```
myapp.directive('translate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var e = $(element);
            var data = attrs.translate;

            var results = $filter('I')(e.html(), data);
            e.html(results.text);
            if (results.tooltip) e.attr('data-tooltip', results.tooltip);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I use it like this:

```
<groupbox title='settings'>
   content
</groupbox>
```

The idea is that the content of the "groupbox" gets put in the div and the title in the "legend". After this the legend needs to be translated by the translate directive. This translation does not happen (it just prints settings). When i replace '{{title}}' with 'settings' it does get translated.

How can i get the translate directive to operate on the results of the groupbox directive.

Comment: Can you share a plunk or jsfiddle with a running example?

Comment: `element` is already a wrapped jQuery element (if you included jQuery before including Angular) or a wrapped Angular [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) element.  html() and attr() are part of jqLite, so you likely don't need jQuery for what you are doing in the link function.  So, you can remove this line: `var e = $(element)` and just use `element`.

Comment: `var data = attrs.translate;` will likely return `undefined` because your groupbox directive is not setting a value for the data-translate attribute.  Maybe try `<legend data-translate="{{title}}">{{title}}</legend>`

Comment: remigio: ill try to make a jsfiddle
@MarkRajcok:
thanks you are correct about je jquery wrapping.
however the empty (data-)translate attribute is by design. The inner html is is used as the key for the lookup of the translation. The value of the data-translate attribute is sometimes used to pass in strings to be replaced into the translation string. This works as intended everywhere else and works here when i replace the binding by the value as discribed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a compile function that puts the title in the legend directly (without binding). That way it is no different then any other use of my translate directive.

```
myapp.directive('groupbox', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template:
            '<fieldset>' +
                '<legend>' +
                    '<span data-translate></span> - ' +
                    '<a data-ng-click="open = !open" data-translate>toggle</a>' +
                '</legend>' +
                '<div data-ng-show="open" data-ng-transclude></div>' +
            '</fieldset>',
        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            element.children('legend').children('span').html(attrs.title);
        }
    };
});
```